# Trouble making an Xwing aim with a crosshair and sight

Tags: mesh, game-engine, physics, tracking, logic-bricks

I have been working on a flight simulator game for a while now, and have run across a problem I can't figure out.  The spaceship is an x wing and I have all the logic with shooting and all that, but I wanted to make it a little more realistic.
I have a set up where the ship is fixed to a cross hair that shows where it is pointing and a circle that shows where the mouse is pointing and it rotates around the ship as you move it. both the circle and the cross hair are the same distance from the ship and rotate around from the center easily because there origin is in the center of the ship and grid.

--This is when it first starts.
[image]

--You can move the circle around by moving mouse around.
[image]

--You can see the distance these are from the ship and their origin.
[image]

My problem is that I want the cross-hair (where the ship is pointing and is parent to the ship) and to move slowly like War Thunder simulation towards wherever the circle (where the mouse is pointing) is. This would create a realistic flying experience. The cross-hair needs to stay the same distance from the ship but I can't get it to rotate on its origin in the center to the circle only travel by location. I should add also I do not know python and have lasted this far on logic bricks in blender.  I have tried different actuators and nothing has worked.

Well, that's the question I've been stumped on for quite a while.  Please help me if you know a way to do it.

Thank you so much!
John